# Why the code goes to else if the statement is true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn my obstacles with level improvement, but for some reason when i tested it in game it doesn't work how i want.

Lets say i start game from 26 level.

I play normally until the level 36, even the 35 level spawning correctly but when player reach level exactly on 36 the code goes into else statement not in else if..

This is my code to spawn obstacles by levels..

```
if (curentLevel > 0  && curentLevel < 10)
{
    SpawnSpawner(0);
}
else if (curentLevel > 10 && curentLevel < 35)
{
    SpawnSpawner(1);
}
else if (curentLevel > 35 && curentLevel < 50)
{
    SpawnSpawner(2);
}
else if (curentLevel > 50 && curentLevel < 60)
{
    SpawnSpawner(5);
}
else 
{

}
```

the code on in else statement gets executed which is empty in my example exactly on level 36.

I hope there is solution why because I told the program to check if curentlevel is higher then 35 which is on 36 level and if the level is smaller then 50 which is 36 , so I don't have idea why then its not executed this code:

```
 else if (curentLevel > 35 && curentLevel < 50)
```

I bet I do something wrong but I hope someone will point me to solution and explain why program doesn't work on my way of thinking, thanks so much...

Comment: The code does not need the > comparisons in each line.  As I read it, it will fall through if the curentLevel = 10 or 35 or 50.  36 - should work, so I don't know.

Comment: you just need to debug your own program. The code looks fine.

Comment: well if `currentLevel==35` when you are on the 36th level, it has to go in the `else` block because none of the other expressions evaluate to true.....

Comment: @Ruzihm , sorry that was my mistake when i paste it from program here.. now edited the same as in my code in unity.   How I can make the same way to spawn levels from 1-10 first block from 10 to 35 second block , from 35 to 50 next block etc.. my code fails but I don't know why it fail

Comment: Whops, yeah - I'm mistaken - Ruzihm is correct. you're checking <35 and >35, so never on 35. (which goes for 10, 35 & 50)

Comment: I suggest you follow @DavidFreeman's suggestion and rid yourself of unnecesary complexity, which in this case causes bugs as well as making the code harder to think about.

Comment: The worst situation is when i force program to go to the 37 level it spawns normally and execute the code in else if statement, only 36 level makes troubles, I don't have idea why.. because it works normally at any other level ...

Comment: Did you read the solution that @Ruzihm explained?

Comment: `only 36 level makes troubles`  The debugger would help you figure this out.

Comment: How I can make it to work on all levels , can somebody point me out.. maybe I add when adding level +1 so that execute on 36 place.. how i can get rid of that no execute levels .. Mabye to check else if ( lvl > 10&& lvl <34); then else if (lvl>35&&lvl<49).. can that fix the problem or i need another solution

Comment: Your ranges are 1-9, 11-34, 36-49, and 51-59.  Are you sure the issue is when `curentLevel` is `36` and not `35`?  You don't see the same issue at (or around) `10` and `50`, too?

Comment: @BACON yes , because the 36 level is actually 35 but it is written in code to add +1 .. so i forget that and that way i thought it happens only on 36 not 35.. my mistake sorry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @Ruzihm's explaination in the comment, you're checking if less than 35 and bigger than 35, so when currentLevel is exactly equal to 35, it will not evaluate true in any conditions.

The solution, as per @DavidFreeman's answer in the comments - the solution to your issue is to make the code less complex:

```
if (curentLevel < 10)
{
    SpawnSpawner(0);
}
else if (curentLevel < 35)
{
    SpawnSpawner(1);
}
else if (curentLevel < 50)
{
    SpawnSpawner(2);
}
else if (curentLevel < 60)
{
    SpawnSpawner(5);
}
else 
{

}
```

The `if (currentLevel > 10)` is redundant, if it doesn't evaluate `true` in `currentLevel < 10` it will definitely be 10 OR MORE in the next `else if`.

If you must use specific ranges, you must take care to include all levels in the conditionals, like @BACON writes, with your current conditions you're covering the currentLevel 1-9, 11-34, 36-49, and 51-59, since `10 < 10 == false` & `10 > 10 == false`. You need to include the 10th level in one of the conditionals, like `10 <= 10 == true`

Comment: Ah so that can work like that. Thank you for pointing me out with all other community members. ty!